# Multiple handlers attached to the same HTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple code. Everytime I click the "Start" button, 3 new buttons with unique IDs and values are created and appended to my div.

For each new button, if I click on it, it alerts the value inside the button. My problem is that if I click the "Start" button 4 times, so there are 12 new buttons created (it's OK), but whenever I click on any newly-created button, it alerts several times (not 1 time as I expect).

I guess the problem is that everytime I click button "Start", a new handler is attached to the button. How to avoid this problem. I have googled for jQuery off(), but it didnt help much. Any help is appreciated very much.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var count =1;

$( document ).ready(function() {

$('#start').on('click', function(e) {
    var i;
    for (i=0;i< 3;i++)
        {
        $('<button id = "Button' + count + '" value = "' + count + '">Button' + count + '</button>').appendTo('#mydiv');    
        count++;
        }       

    for(i=1;i<= count;i++)
        {
        $(document).on("click", '#Button' + i , function(){
              alert (  $(this).attr('value')  );
            });         
        }               
});

});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<h1>Test dynamically created button</h1>

<div id = "mydiv">

<button id ="start">START</button> 

</div>                       

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your guess is correct. You added handlers several times. This is fix.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$( document ).ready(function() {
var count = 1; //no need to make it global

$('#start').on('click', function(e) {
    var i;
    for (i=0;i< 3;i++)
        {
        $('<button id = "Button' + count + '" value = "' + count + '">Button' + count + '</button>')
            .click(function(){//add handler when button created... and never more
              alert (this.value);//or $(this).val()
            })         
            .appendTo('#mydiv');    
        count++;
        }       
    /* here you add handlers more and more times
    for(i=1;i<= count;i++)
        {
        $(document).on("click", '#Button' + i , function(){
              alert (  $(this).attr('value')  );
            });         
        } 
    */
});

});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<h1>Test dynamically created button</h1>

<div id = "mydiv">

<button id ="start">START</button> 

</div>                       

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your buttons stay in the DOM (like it seems at the moment), why don't you add the EventListener directly on the new added buttons like this:

```
$('#start').on('click', function(e) {
    var i;
    for (i=0;i< 3;i++) {
        var myNewButton = $('<button id = "Button' + count + '" value = "' + count + '">Button' + count + '</button>');
        myNewButton.appendTo('#mydiv');
        myNewButton.on("click", function() {
              alert (  $(this).attr('value')  );
        });
        count++;
     }               
});
```

Otherwise, as you already guessed in your question, you adding additional Listeners to your existing buttons since you loop through all of them.

Answer (score 0):

At every click on start you create event handlers also for the buttons that are already on the page, meaning they get several handlers attached to them, the more you click on the start button.

Simply add the following handler on document ready (not on click), and it will capture any future button's click if it has an id like `Button*`:

```
$(document).on('click', '[id^=Button]', function () {
    alert ($(this).attr('value')  );
});
```

Remove the creation of such click handler from the start button's handler.

So the code becomes:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var count = 0;

    $(document).on('click', '[id^=Button]', function () {
        alert ($(this).attr('value')  );
    });

    $('#start').on('click', function(e) {
        var i;
        for (i=0;i<3;i++) {
            $('<button id = "Button' + count + '" value = "' + count + '">Button' + count + '</button>').appendTo('#mydiv');    
            count++;
        } 
    });
});
```

So this way, you only have two handlers: one for the start button, and one for all other `Button*` buttons. No need to dynamically add new handlers.